# Python 3.4.4. Telegram bot. Ошибка: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, telegram

Ругается так:

> @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Код:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(constants.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def handle_text(message):

    if message.text == "A":
       bot.send_message(message.chat_id, "B")
```

Comment: а зачем нужна собака

Comment: @vitidev это синтактис декораторов

Comment: U menya toje chat.id no govorit tak

Answer (score 1):

У объекта [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) нет атрибута `chat_id`. Вместо этого к `id` чата можно обратиться через объект [Chat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat), который присутствует в `message`: `message.chat.id`.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handler_text(message):
    if message.text == 'A':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'B')
```